# Maven release:prepare goal

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, maven-2, maven-release-plugin

We have the following config in our POM file:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>surefire-it</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This ensures that the tests are not executed during **test** phase. Tests are executed only during **integration-test** phase.

However, when we prepare for release (release:prepare), maven executes the tests during **test** phase. This causes our build to fail because our tests can be run only during Integration test phase (we use tomcat-maven plugin to deploy the packaged war before the tests can be executed).

I know that we can skip the tests by passing the parameter (-DskipTests etc.). We do not want to skip any tests, we just want release:prepare to execute just like any other maven goal.

Any suggestion/help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the more general approach to disable the `maven-surefire-plugin` completely during `test` phase.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <!-- Disable the default-test by putting it in phase none -->
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <!-- Enable the test during integration-test phase -->
            <id>surefire-it</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

---

**Edit**

This is the output from my dry run of `mvn release:prepare` with the above configured surefire plugin:

```
C:\Users\maba\Development\svn\local\stackoverflow\Q12840869>mvn release:prepare -DdryRun
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Q12840869-1.0-SNAPSHOT 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.0:prepare (default-cli) @ Q12840869 ---
[INFO] Resuming release from phase 'scm-check-modifications'
[INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --non-interactive status"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\maba\Development\svn\local\stackoverflow\Q12840869
[INFO] Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
What is the release version for "Q12840869-1.0-SNAPSHOT"? (com.stackoverflow:Q12840869) 1.0: :
What is SCM release tag or label for "Q12840869-1.0-SNAPSHOT"? (com.stackoverflow:Q12840869) Q12840869-1.0: :
What is the new development version for "Q12840869-1.0-SNAPSHOT"? (com.stackoverflow:Q12840869) 1.1-SNAPSHOT: :
[INFO] Transforming 'Q12840869-1.0-SNAPSHOT'...
[INFO] Not generating release POMs
[INFO] Executing preparation goals - since this is simulation mode it is running against the original project, not the rewritten ones
[INFO] Executing goals 'clean verify'...
[WARNING] Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
[INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building Q12840869-1.0-SNAPSHOT 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ Q12840869 ---
[INFO] [INFO] Deleting C:\Users\maba\Development\svn\local\stackoverflow\Q12840869\target
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ Q12840869 ---
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ Q12840869 ---
[INFO] [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\maba\Development\svn\local\stackoverflow\Q12840869\target\classes
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ Q12840869 ---
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\maba\Development\svn\local\stackoverflow\Q12840869\src\test\resources
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Q12840869 ---
[INFO] [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\maba\Development\svn\local\stackoverflow\Q12840869\target\test-classes
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) @ Q12840869 ---
[INFO] [INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\maba\Development\svn\local\stackoverflow\Q12840869\target\Q12840869-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.2:test (surefire-it) @ Q12840869 ---
[INFO] [INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\maba\Development\svn\local\stackoverflow\Q12840869\target\surefire
-reports
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.stackoverflow.MainTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.041 sec
[INFO]
[INFO] Results :
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 5.102s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: Thu Oct 11 17:10:29 CEST 2012
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/147M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I tried this, but it did not have any effect. The tests continue to get executed in 'test' phase.

Comment: @saravana_pc They continue to get executed with `release:prepare` or with `mvn install`?

Comment: release:prepare. We do not face any issues while doing the following:             mvn install (or)                                                             mvn deploy

Comment: @saravana_pc That's strange because for me when running `release:prepare` with my configuration the `default-test` is not run.

Comment: @saravana_pc Added the output from my own `release:prepare` and I don't get any output that my tests has been run in the `test` phase. The tests are being run after the `jar` has been built which is in the `package` phase. You can see that the `maven-surefire-plugin` is only called for once.

Comment: I compared the console output above with the output of my application. They look identical. In both the cases, the tests are executed in **test** phase. Hence the tests are failing in my case.

Comment: @saravana_pc I strongly disagree that the tests are being run in **test** phase. They are being run in **integration-test** as intended.

Comment: Can you please let me know how we can confirm it is being run in **integration-test** phase ?

Comment: @saravana_pc Try with `mvn -X release:prepare`.

Comment: @saravana_pc Also, remove the two lines I added to not run in `test` phase, the `<id>default-test</id>` and `<phase>none</phase>`. Then you will see that the tests will be run twice. First in `test` phase and then in `integration-test` phase.

Answer (score 3):

I would try an alternate approach, and try to configure the release plugin to always use `-DskipTests` as an argument so you don't need to specify it each time:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin<artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <arguments>-DskipTests</arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In theory this should append `-DskipTests` to the arguments that the `prepare` and `release` goals pass to the sub-executions of Maven that they execute.

Comment: this parameter will ensure that the tests are never run. we would like the integration tests to get executed.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`maven-failsafe-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/) for the integration tests, and keep `maven-surefire-plugin` for the unit tests.

This will guarantee that the unit tests are completely segregated from the integration tests (and can therefore be turned off separately), and the integration tests are run during the "`integration-test` and `verify` phases of the build lifecycle".

Answer (score 2):

Add your integration tests in a separate profile which isn't active by default. Add a triggerring rule or something. Then invoke the builds with the integration tests on a need by need basis. For example, on your CI (Jenkins/Hudson, TeamCity, Bamboo, etc) triggered the profile.

The problem you are currently facing is that you haven't made a separation between the two types of tests and when they should run. You have simply defined the phases you would like them to execute in. This isn't sufficient knowledge of the execution context for Maven to figure out what you would like to do and it invokes them during the release as well.

Comment: @carlspring- thanks for the reply. The tests are executed as expected for the goals clean, install, deploy etc. It is only when we do release:prepare, that we face these issues.

Comment: Similarly, like mattb suggests, you can define arguments -`P!yourProfile` in order to skip it.